# User control dynamically populated loading blank

Tags: user-controls, dynamically-generated

having an issue here with a user control that I'm populating some html input tags dynamically at run time. See below for html in control.

Creation of dynamic field in user control:

```
foreach (InputItem inputItem in searchFunctions)
    {             
%>
    <tr> 
        <th><label id="Label2"><%inputItem.Text.AsString();%></label></th>
            <td>
            <%
                inputItem.Html.ToString();
                %>
            </td>
    </tr>
<%  
    }                      
%>
```

The problem is on page_load of the page using the control. I'm taking the referenced control and initializing it (see code below). But it appears not to be taking. The page is loading the control blank, as if it loads it before it is populated with any data.

I do know that the code is definitely getting to the dynamic population part, and the html is sound. Even if it wasn't the inputItem.Text on the label would be coming through, but its blank as well.

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    BindData();
}

protected void BindData()
{
    Common.PopulateListFromDataTable(UnitOfMeasure.GetUnitOfMeasureByGroupName("weight"), unitOfMeasure, "UnitOfMeasure", "UnitOfMeasureLong");
    unitOfMeasure.SelectedIndex = unitOfMeasure.Items.IndexOf(unitOfMeasure.Items.FindByText("pounds"));
    InitializeOrderSearch();

}

protected void InitializeOrderSearch()
{
    List<InputItem> searchFunctions = new List<InputItem> 
    {
        new InputItem("text","BillingCompany","BillingCompany","Company Name","100px"),
        new InputItem("text","PurchaseOrderNumber","PurchaseOrderNumber","PO#","100px"),
        new InputItem("dropdown","OrderStatus","OrderStatus","Status","100px"),
    };

    List<string> columns = new List<string>()
    {
        "PurchaseOrderNumber",
        "ProcessDate",
        "Status"
    };

    //OrderSearch1 is name of control from aspx
    OrderSearch1.searchFunctions = searchFunctions;
    OrderSearch1.columns = columns;
}
```

I've tried things such as below as well with no luck, an error is thrown saying it can't covert from type control to type ASP.control. Any ideas, kinda at a loss here.

```
protected void BindData()
{
    Common.PopulateListFromDataTable(UnitOfMeasure.GetUnitOfMeasureByGroupName("weight"), unitOfMeasure, "UnitOfMeasure", "UnitOfMeasureLong");
    unitOfMeasure.SelectedIndex = unitOfMeasure.Items.IndexOf(unitOfMeasure.Items.FindByText("pounds"));
    this.OrderSearch1 = InitializeOrderSearch();

}

protected admin_controls_OrderSearch InitializeOrderSearch()
{
    admin_controls_OrderSearch blah = new admin_controls_OrderSearch();
    List<InputItem> searchFunctions = new List<InputItem> 
    {
        new InputItem("text","BillingCompany","BillingCompany","Company Name","100px"),
        new InputItem("text","PurchaseOrderNumber","PurchaseOrderNumber","PO#","100px"),
        new InputItem("dropdown","OrderStatus","OrderStatus","Status","100px"),
    };

    List<string> columns = new List<string>()
    {
        "PurchaseOrderNumber",
        "ProcessDate",
        "Status"
    };

    //OrderSearch1 is name of control from aspx
    blah.searchFunctions = searchFunctions;
    blah.columns = columns;
    return blah;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this syntax to output text to page's html from server-side script:

```
<tr> 
    <th><label id="Label2"><%= inputItem.Text.AsString() %></label></th>
    <td><%= inputItem.Html.ToString() %></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Wow that did the trick, got in too deep on the dynamic controls and couldn't see the light lol. Duh momement, thank you much.